# Can an XSL template match in *ALL* modes?

Tags: xslt

Is there a way to write an XSL 1.0 template which is matching in all modes?

Or do I have to write a separate template for every existing mode (including additional templates for modes being added in the future)?

Here is what I have:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="mode1" />
    ...
<xsl:apply-templates mode="mode2" />
    ...
<!-- Do not process text content of nodes no matter in what mode -->
<!-- Is there a way to have only one template here? -->
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="mode1" />
<xsl:template match="text()" mode="mode2" />
```

Comment: @divo I will not recommend to anyone to use #all in XSLT 2.0 -- it is too-dangerous. For example, just a little more generic template (matching node()) will interfere with *any other* template. Much better is to design one's templates more carefully, in a more clean way, so that #all is not needed.

Comment: @divo You don't need empty templates matching text() if you use <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::text())]"/> instead of using <xsl:apply-templates/>

Comment: @Dimitre: Yes, of course you are right. However, your solution implies modifying every apply-templates in the code which makes maintenance quite hard and seems error-prone to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The predefined mode: [`#all`](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSL-Ref/Tutorials/Modes/m4.html) (only available in XSLT 2.0 however).

edit: replicating shared mode behaviour with 1.0

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="choice" select="'a'"/><!-- input seed here -->
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$choice='a'">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="a"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$choice='b'">
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="b"/>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="a">
    [A]
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="b">
    [B]
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    [ALL]
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: That would be really nice to have! Thanks for the answer, but it's seems XSLT 2.0 only and I forgot to mention that I'm restricted using XSLT 1.0 :-( Seems I will have to write a separate template anyway...

Comment: Ah, in that case you should at least be able to wrap the common code in a named or modeless template you can call from within the two mode forks.

Comment: @annakata I don't see how your XSLT 1.0 code would act as if there is a template that is selected in all modes. Could you, please, edit your answer and explain?

Comment: As I understand your workaround works only nicely unless you have other modeless templates, e.g. <xsl:template match="someNode"> which might get triggered by the additional <xsl:apply-templates />

Comment: oh yeah, it's *very* situational, but for some specific cases it can work - I'm really just saying that there are ways of getting the commonality into a template and minimising duplication. The worst case scenario though is still that you could use named templates instead of apply-templates

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to write an XSL 1.0
>   template which is matching in all
>   modes

**Yes, in order to do this one should follow these two rules**:

1. Write your template **without a mode attribute**.
2. Within the moded templates have an `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction **without a mode attribute** that will result in the template in 1. above being selected for processing

**This follows directly from the [XSLT 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) spec, [which says](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#modes)**:

> If an `xsl:apply-templates` element has
>   a `mode` attribute, then it applies only
>   to those template rules from
>   `xsl:template` elements that have a `mode`
>   attribute with the same value; if an
>   `xsl:apply-templates` element does not
>   have a `mode` attribute, then it applies
>   only to those template rules from
>   `xsl:template` elements that do not have
>   a `mode` attribute.

**To summarise**: A set of templates each in a different mode can still issue `<xsl:apply-templates>` in such a way (described above), so that the same specific, single template will be selected for processing in each case.

Comment: This might work in the simple example presented here. However, this might have side-effect when there is more than one modeless template. The exacet behaviour of XSLT 2.0's #all mode is not available in XSLT 1.0 and can hardly be simulated.

Comment: @divo  I will not recommend to anyone to use #all in XSLT 2.0 -- it is too-dangerous. For example, just a little more generic template (matching node()) will interfere with *any other* template. Much better is to design one's templates more carefully, in a more clean way, so that #all is not needed.

Comment: Yes, it should be used with care, but it depends strongly on the scenario. In my case the content of leave elements should *never* appear in output, hence the empty template(s) matching text(). I don't see the problem with a more generic template though, since "more specific" have higher priority.

Comment: @divo THis is more complicated, especially if templates are imported.

Comment: @divo You don't need empty templates matching text() if you use <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::text())]"/> instead of using <xsl:apply-templates/>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the template match in all modes then why are you using mode? If you don't use mode then the template will be used all the time. The reason for mode is to conditionally do different things with the same data type. Seems like you want modeless.

Comment: not quite, if you were already within a mode fork (for some useful purpose) default mode templates will not be referenced

Comment: No, I need several modes to process nodes several times doing different things. However, I don't want to process the content of certain nodes in any mode. The only solution seems to write a separate template for each mode.

Comment: (continued) And a modeless template will only match a modeless apply-templates "call".